# svg begin="mouseover"not working

Tags: svg, mouseover

Im new at coding and am trying to make a simple line rotate around its center using svg.

I have got the line rotating but everytime I add begin="mouseover" the animation no longer starts.

If anyone could help me get this working with a hover event I will be greatly appreciated.

```
<svg>

      <line id="line_01" x1="20" y1="100" 
          x2="100" y2="20" 
          stroke="black" 
          stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" />

  <animateTransform 
           xlink:href="#line_01"
           attributeName="transform" 
           pointer-events="all"
           attributeType="XML"
           type="rotate"
           from="0 60 60"
           to="360 60 60" 
           dur="3s"
           />

</svg>
```

Comment: What browser?  Works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to precede mouseover with the id of an element e.g.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

      <line id="line_01" x1="20" y1="100" 
          x2="100" y2="20" 
          stroke="black" 
          stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" />

  <animateTransform 
           xlink:href="#line_01"
           begin="line_01.mouseover"
           attributeName="transform" 
           pointer-events="all"
           attributeType="XML"
           type="rotate"
           from="0 60 60"
           to="360 60 60" 
           dur="3s"
           />

</svg>
```